# Shared Preferences doesnt work

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I need your help here..
I have the following code:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
TextView test1;
String punkte, points;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    test1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test1);

    punkte = points;
    SharedPreferences load = getSharedPreferences(punkte, 0);
    points = load.getString("punkte", "0");
    test1.setText(points);
    }    


public void mehrPunkte() {
    punkte = "3";


    SharedPreferences load = getSharedPreferences(punkte, 0);
    points = load.getString("punkte", "0");
    test1.setText(points);

    SharedPreferences save = getSharedPreferences(punkte, 0);
    save.edit().putString("punkte", punkte).commit();
}
```

But it still shows "0" if i restart the app.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: I see no call to `mehrPunkte`...

Comment: It's called in a onClick-method:public void onClick(View v) { mehrPunkte();}

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter of [getSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) is its name, and you save it to a different shared preferences, indicated by the value of the `punkte` variable. Try this instead:

```
final private static String SHARED_PREF_ID = "My shared preferences";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    SharedPreferences load = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_ID, MODE_PRIVATE);
    // ...
} 

public void mehrPunkte() {
    punkte = "3";

    SharedPreferences load = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_ID, MODE_PRIVATE);
    points = load.getString("punkte", "0");
    test1.setText(points);

    SharedPreferences save = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_ID, MODE_PRIVATE);
    save.edit().putString("punkte", punkte).commit();
}
```

Also, use constants to indicate the mode, not integer literals (MODE_PRIVATE, not 0)

Answer (score 0):

Put `mehrPunkte();` in `onCreate()`

Comment: look my comment above: the method is called and than it shows "3". But when i restart it shows "0" again

Comment: Binyamin Sharet's answer is what you're looking for.